# Rank of the product of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Assume that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times \nu}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{\nu\times \nu}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{\nu\times n}$. I'm interested in the rank of the matrix
$$AB^{-1}C.$$
$A$ and $C$ are full rank ($n$), and of course, $B$ is as well ($\nu$). In light of this operation I'm wondering if:

- Is there any explicit condition so that $\operatorname{rank}(M)=n$?
- Can I say something about $\operatorname{rank}(AB^{-1}C)$ using $\operatorname{rank}(ABC)$ instead? (that would be much easier for my problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer you second question first: unfortunately no, the conditions are not equivalent. Take
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, C = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $A^TBC = 0$ but $A^T B^{-1}C = 1.$ Here the matrix $B$ was carefully crafted to rotate the image of $C$ into the kernel of $A^T$, but not vice-versa.

For the first question, I know of no simple condition (simpler than performing the multiplication and probing the product's rank). You can take the SVD of $A$ and $C$ and try to reason how B maps the different subspaces to each other, but at that point you're already better off taking the determinant...

Comment: Thanks a million for the answer. Extremely clear example! I'll follow your advice with the SVD... It will be a little messy since $A$,$B$ and $C$ are the result of several Kronecker products/sums. Thanks again!